# How to calculate a date but exclude weekends in microsoft access?

Tags: database, excel, ms-access

I work for a homebuilder and I am trying to help a co-worker out with getting a formula that can calculate a date 3 days out but exclude weekends.

```
DateAdd("d",3,[TrussOrderDate])
```

this is the current formula she is using and she was looking to get this to calculate the date, but exclude weekends

Comment: It is usually a good idea to use a calendar table. It will allow you to fill in all days that are holidays, not just weekends.

Answer (score 3):

I would create a table, that will hold all the (Bank/Public/Special) holidays. Something like (tbl_BankHolidays),

```
holID   |   bankDate    |   bankHoliday     |   workDay
--------+---------------+-------------------+-----------
1       |   01/01/2014  |   New years day   |   Wednesday
2       |   18/04/2014  |   Good Friday     |   Friday
3       |   21/04/2014  |   Easter Monday   |   Monday
4       |   05/05/2014  |   Early May       |   Monday
5       |   26/05/2014  |   Spring holiday  |   Monday
6       |   25/08/2014  |   Summer holiday  |   Monday
7       |   25/12/2014  |   Christmas Day   |   Thursday
8       |   26/12/2014  |   Boxing Day      |   Friday
9       |   01/01/2015  |   New Year’s Day  |   Thursday
:
:
16      |   28/12/2015  |   Boxing Day      |   Monday
```

Then a Function to calculate these dates.

```
Function addWorkDays(addNumber As Long, Date2 As Date) As Date
'********************'
'Code Courtesy of    '
'  Paul Eugin        '
'********************'

    Dim finalDate As Date
    Dim i As Long, tmpDate As Date
    tmpDate = Date2
    i = 1
    Do While i <= addNumber
        If Weekday(tmpDate) <> 1 And Weekday(tmpDate) <> 7 And _
            DCount("*", "tbl_BankHolidays", "bankDate = " & CDbl(tmpDate)) = 0 Then i = i + 1
        tmpDate = DateAdd("d", 1, tmpDate)
    Loop

    addWorkDays = tmpDate

End Function
```

When you need to add *n* number of *days* to a date, you simply use, similar to DateAdd function. You do not specify the String identifier as this defaults to adding just days. Then first argument is the number of days to add. The second would be the date to which the days needs to be added.

The code works, by looping one day at a time, checks if it is a Weekend (1 - vbSunday, or 7 - vbSaturday), or if it listed in the special day off table. If it is a day off or weekend, add one day to the day without incrementing the counter. The loop will terminate when the counter is equal to the number you passed !

Comment: I think that placing `tmpDate = DateAdd("d", 1, tmpDate)` BEFORE the `if` in the `do` loop is more accurate.